# Enter-PSSession to remote server fails with "cannot find the computer"

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

My desktop is win7 and I am trying to connect to a server 2012.
Both hosts are on the same domain.

If I do:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName *ServerName***
```

I get the following failure message from winrm

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server xxx failed with the 
>   following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using 
>   Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer xxx. Verify that the 
>   computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly.*

It doesn't matter if I use just the server name or if I enter it fully qualified.

Both systems show `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion  4 0 -1 -1`

I have tried the various troubleshooting hints that I found i.e.
run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` and also set `TrustedHosts = *` on both sides.
I also disabled the firewall service on both sides.
When I try to Enter-PSSession from the server to my desktop it works as desired.
But from my desktop to the server I always get the error message that the computer cannot be found.

Comment: Ping is successful on the short name as well as on the FQDN in both directions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After talking to our domain admin I think I found the cause of the problem.
The server is in a resource domain which only has a one way trust to the main OU.
This explains why I can do PS remoting from the server to the clients but not vice versa.
I found that I can use the IP address with the `-Credential` option in my case though which isn't nice but an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Here is [a page](https://www.techtutsonline.com/windows-powershell-remoting/) with more details how to enable WinRM remoting between one way trusted domains (look under Configure PowerShell Remoting). Basically it's `Set-Item WSMan:\\localhost\client\TrustedHosts -Value <IP or Machine name> -Concatenate -Force`

Comment: Thank you @Stoinov this one line made everything work! Perfect! To all others ..... -Value is the machine you want to connect to. Run this line 1st then run your Invoke-Command. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely caused by your netbios name being different from the server's hostname. Try to connect with the netbios name instead.

- Determine the correct name by running the following command in powershell:

"$env:COMPUTERNAME.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"

Comment: This led me to my solution..I was originally trying with a DNS name but it only worked when I used the computer name (even through the DNS resolves to that computer)

Comment: This is only correct if your user is in the same domain as the machine, in my case it is not. The correct command to get the server domain is:
(Get-CimInstance -class Win32_ComputerSystem | % {$_.Name+'.'+$_.Domain})

Answer (score 1):

run `winrm quickconfig` from a powershell session on the remote machine

Comment: "PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm quickconfig" gives:  
WinRM service is already running on this machine.  
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.  

But `Enter-PSSession` still gives the same error message.   
I have found that the problem does not exist on a VM which I have setup for test purposes but on my actual physical desktop.  

I am still looking for hints to troubleshoot the problem as the error message doesn't give me any valuable clue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case DNS was was pointing to the right IP yet there wase a typo in the hostname so basicaly the parameter -Computername and the actual hostname didn't match.

Comment: Yes, this. Just had a very similar problem. Wasn't DNS but rather that the hostname was longer than 15-characters, which is the NETBIOS limit! Shorted it to 15 characters and all Enter-PSSession worked.

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late but i am putting my fix to the few sites that experienced the same issue.

For me it was a duplicate computer name in the root domain. I found it by running `setspn -f -q */servername`. This popped up the server name in multiple domains.  deleting the invalid machine from the root AD and root dns, and i was up and running.