# Why can't I get Powershell Remoting to work using Hostname?

Tags: powershell, winrm

`New-PSSession` does not work when using the `HostName` of a server, but does with the `IP`. Both local and remote machines are on the same domain.

```
> PS C:\Windows\system32> New-PSSession -ComputerName "SERVERNAME"

New-PSSession : [SERVERNAME] Connecting to remote server SERVERNAME failed with the  
following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred  
while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer SERVERNAME. Verify that the  
computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more  
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

I've also tried Ping, RDP and `Test-WSMan` which are all successful using the servers `Hostname`.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you resolve the IP if you use nslookup?

Comment: Just did it now and Yes I can

Comment: My guess from the error is the DC authenticating you couldn't reach the server. Is it in DNS network wide, or just resolvable from your machine? Or not resolvable from the DC?

Comment: There's another similar question that talks about the issue being due to one way trust and workaround of passing credentials directly with the `-credential` parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30568727/2796058

Comment: A) Shouldn't be a one way trust since its on same domain.
B) I would have expected the error message to be different from a DC authenticating issue. Something like "No Logon Servers Found" or Access denied type message. Would this not be the case?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like SelfSignedCertificate issue.

Delete the old WinRM listener

```
winrm delete winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
```

Create New-SelfSignedCertificate with Domain name

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "<YOUR_DNS_NAME>" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

Update the SelfSignedCertificate _THUMBPRINT

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="<YOUR_DNS_NAME>"; CertificateThumbprint="<COPIED_CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT>"
```

3.Add a new firewall rule

```
$port=5986
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTPS-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$port
```

Please refer to this link for more info:

http://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/devops/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https-manually